# How boto3 is configured on AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

As I understand the `boto3` module has to be configured (for specifying `aws_access_key_id` and
`aws_secret_access_key`) before I could use it to access any AWS service.

As from the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html) , the three ways of configuration are:
1.A Config object that's created and passed as the config parameter when creating a client
2.Environment variables
3.The ~/.aws/config file

However, for the examples I have read that there is no need to configure if writing directly on AWS lambda. Moreover, there are no environment variables and I could not find the config file. How is `boto3`configured on AWS lambda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> there are no environment variables

Yes, they are. They are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime). Each function has access to many env variables, inluding:

> AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SESSION_TOKEN – The access keys obtained from the **function's execution role**.

So boto3 takes its credentials from these env variables. And these variables are populated from your function execution role which your function assumes.

Answer (score 0):

When you create an AWS Lambda function, you select an IAM Role that the function will use.

Your code within the function will be automatically supplied the credentials associated with that IAM Role. **There is no need to provide any credentials.** (Think of it as being the same way that software running on an Amazon EC2 instance receives credentials from an IAM Role.)